# Javascript подсветка "корневого" пункта меню при переходе в подпукнт

Tags: javascript

У меня есть пункт в меню **Новости** `\news\`. При переходе к конкретной новости мне необходимо, чтобы пункт меню **Новости** оставался активным, например, `\news\foo`. То есть подсвечился "корневой" пункт вне зависимости от вложенности. Как это можно сделать?

Comment: Проверьте, есть ли в текущей ссылке вхождение ссылки пункта меню.

Comment: @oliver-patterson спасибо за помощь. Да, я пробовал так делать, но дело в том, что у меню в пункте меню есть ссылка на главную страницу `http://127.0.0.1:5500/` и из-за этого получается, что она может иметь вхождение на любой пункт меню.

Comment: Отсортируйте строки от меньшего к большему.. Не знаю даже)